# ¿Como muestro es valor (mayor que)?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-11g

Tengo una query en donde debo mostrar un registro con ganancias mayores a 40.000...
Hice esto

```
SELECT p.COD_PROD AS TIPO_PRODUCTO,
   to_char(round(sum(d.costo_sali)),'$999,999,999') as "Total Costo",
   to_char(round(sum(d.venta_sali)),'$999,999,999') as "Total Venta",
   to_char(round(sum(d.venta_sali - d.costo_sali)*100 / d.venta_sali)) as "PORC_Ganancia" ,
   to_char(round(sum(d.venta_sali - d.costo_sali)),'$999,999,999') Ganancia
FROM PRODUCTO p JOIN DET_SALIDA d
ON(P.Cod_Prod = D.Cod_Prod)
GROUP BY p.cod_prod,D.Venta_Sali
ORDER BY Ganancia DESC;
```

Había pensado en agregar `WHERE Ganancias > 40.000` pero obviamente 'Ganancias' no es un identificador de por si y no sé como debo hacerlo correctamente...

---

estaba en la duda si usar having o where pero el tema es que Ganancia no es una tabla si no que yo le llame Ganancia a una formula (venta-salida) y no me lo detecta como identificador válido... ¿Cómo podría darle valor como identificador , asi como una variable propia que almacene esos datos?

Comment: Etiquetaste MySQL y Oracle 11g, al haber ciertas diferencias al usar `GROUP BY` entre ambos motores de BDD, puedes recibir respuestas/comentarios imprecisos o equivocados.

Answer (score 4):

Cuando haces uso de una función de agregación como:

- `SUM`
- `AVG`
- `COUNT`

Debes utilizar a **`HAVING`** de este modo:

```
HAVING Ganancia > 40000
```

Ya que:

- **`HAVING`** trabaja sobre el conjunto de resultados que te devuelve la función de agregación que usas

Solo ten en consideración que el uso de **`HAVING`** va:

- Después de la instrucción **`GROUP BY`**
- Antes de la instrucción **`ORDER BY`**

**Referencias**

- [HAVING Clausula](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la clausula `HAVING` como te indican en la otra respuesta, pero yo lo haría sobre la propia formula de la ganancia, es decir:

```
HAVING sum(d.venta_sali - d.costo_sali) > 40000
```

De esta forma la condición es sobre datos numéricos (más eficiente), no sobre un campo VARCHAR formateado, en el ejemplo, el valor de `Ganancia` es un VARCHAR con valores como: `'$40.423'`

Comment: ¿Puedes sustentar lo del VARCHAR formateado?

Comment: ¿ A qué te refieres ? La condición con un número en BBDD siempre es más eficiente. En la query "Ganancia" se genera con un `to_char`, y para preguntar por una cantidad, es más lógico usar un dato numérico.